# How to access the .csv file directory through array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, csv

I have created save button which I guess going to create a .csv file to store x,y and name of the object on screen since I can't check it because I can't access the file its created

```
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let objectsName = stringObjectName.joined(separator: ",")
    let coX = stringObjectX.joined(separator: ",")
    let coY = stringObjectY.joined(separator: ",")

    let fileName = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("output.csv")
    CSVFilesName.append(fileName)

    var csvText = "Name, Data X, Data Y\n"

    let count = stringObjectName.count

    if count > 0 {
        for _ in 0..<(stringObjectName.count-1) {
            let newLine = "\(objectsName),\(coX),\(coY)\n"

            csvText.append(contentsOf: newLine)
        }
    }

    do {
        try csvText.write(to: fileName, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

    print(fileName)
}
```

after this I try to access the file call "output.csv" which it is suppose to store in document directory in another viewport. So, I created the method to pass the method from another view controller to current view controller by using and store CSVFile

```
 var CSVFileName = [URL]()

    func assignArray() {

    let cameraVC = CameraViewController()
    CSVFileName = cameraVC.CSVFilesName
    print(CSVFileName)

}
```

and the problem start here since I have array which suppose to store file name in String

```
 let fileNames = ["sth1.csv", "sth2.csv"]
```

but I can't find the convert CSVFileName from saving button to String, and replace "static array" into "dynamic array" and change the method below to get 
URL from FileManager().default.url instead of fileURL to give TableViewController data to show and accessible

```
     private func prepareFileURLS() {
    for file in fileNames {
        let fileParts = file.components(separatedBy: ".")
        print(fileParts[0])
        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileParts[0], withExtension: fileParts[1]) {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                print(fileURL)
                fileURLs.append(fileURL as NSURL)
            }
        }
    }
    print(fileURLs)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can read Your CSV file :

```
func filterMenuCsvData()
        {
          do {
                // This solution assumes  you've got the file in your bundle
                if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "products_category", ofType: "csv"){
                    // STORE CONTENT OF FILE IN VARIABLE 
                    let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    var rows : [String] = []
                    var readData =  [String]()
                    rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                    for data in 0..<rows.count - 1{
                        if data == 0 || rows[data].contains(""){
                          continue
                        }
                        readData = rows[data].components(separatedBy: ",")
                        Category.append(readData[0])
                        if readData[2] != ""{
                        Occassions.append(readData[2])
                        }
                       selectedOccassionsRadioButtonIndex = Array(repeating: false, count: Occassions.count)
                       selectedCategoryRadioButtonIndex = Array(repeating: false, count: Category.count)
                    }
               }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                // do something with Error}
            print(err)
        }
    }
```